# Getting a value inside props using variable

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-props

Has anyone tried getting a particular value inside a prop using a variable?

Normally, getting a particular data in props goes like

```
const dataValue = props.table.data.rowData.account_number
```

However in this instance I need the last part of the props to be a variable, because
the `account_number` value is not fixed and the name varies.

So is there a way that I use a variable instead of adding a fixed name on the past part of the prop call?

Like so:

```
let theVariable = *somethingNew*;


const dataValue = props.table.data.rowData.theVariable
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this through property bracket access:

```js
let theVariable = somethingNew;

const dataValue = props.table.data.rowData[theVariable]
```

This can also be used during object creation:

```js
const dataValue = {
   [theVariable]: {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do like this:

```
let theVariable = *somethingNew*;
const dataValue = props.table.data.rowData[theVariable];
```